# how to see text log in Log.d() command in android studio 4.0

Tags: android

in onCreate function, i have command log, but android studio 4.0 had not Android Monitor window. How to i see text in Log.d() command.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    
        Log.d("function:","onCreate in main acitivity");
    }
```

Comment: We have logecat in AS4

Answer (score 1):

It is not about Android studio 4.0. just google it before asking.

however, you can see all logs in the Logcat.

[image]